# WPF Combobox cleared

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a DataTemplate that I use to display part of a class within a TabControl (it is the DataTemplate for a TabItem). This DataTemplate has multiple ComboBoxes that display various property values to the user.

I have a ComboBox that allows the user to switch between objects that the TabControl is bound to.

If the Object has properties that are not null, then they are selected in the ComboBoxes that are bound to them (as expected).

If I switch to an Object that has a null property, then there is no item selected in the ComboBox (also, as expected).

However, if I switch back to the Object that has a value in the property, it is not being displayed at all.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the XAML markup for the DataTemplate that I am having problems with...I'm only going to post 1 ComboBox since they are all acting the same way:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OptionalInfoTemplate">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <Label Content="Optional Item 1:"></Label>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=DataContext.OptionalItems}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=OptionalItem1}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <!-- more controls -->
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DataTemplate x:Key="OptionalInfoTemplate">
```

Thank you for your time and help!

-Frinny

Comment: "it is not being displayed correctly." --
What exactly do you see happening?

Comment: It is not being displayed at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem accidentally.
I changed the binding for the ComboBox's ItemsSource property from:

```
"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=DataContext.OptionalItems}"
```

To:

```
"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=DataContext.OptionalItems}"
```

-Frinny